# Oracle OLE DB provider for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, oracle-11g

I have installed 11G Oracle OLE db provider on Windows Server 2008 Release 2. I can find it in the registry but I can't see it in "create a new ODBC connections" wizard.

Any help please?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. It needed newer version.